# How to make cursor dissapear after inactivity in Unity

Tags: c#, timer, mouse, unity-game-engine

My goal is simple, like a lot of applications, I want to make **my cursor invisible after a certain time of inactivity** of my user.

My solution doesn't seem really **optimized**, here's the **algorithm** :

```
void Start {
    Timer t = new Timer(5000);//Create a timer of 5 second
    t.start();
}

void Update {
    if(MouseMoved){
        t.reset();
    }
    timeLeft = t.deltaTime;
    if ( timeLeft == 5000 )
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }
}
```

I really **don't like to check at every frame** if the mouse is moved, I'd prefer that my mouse moved trigger something, but I'm lost here, is anyone have a better solution ?

Comment: **don't like to check at every frame** What you are looking for is the `mouse move event` which is available in almost every App API except for Unity. Unity does not have that. Your only solution now is to make a native C++ plugin. But if you do it, this means that you will have to make one for Linux and Mac too. This is not worth it for this simple thing.

Comment: You should check if the input affects anything coz it looks like micro optimisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to check for things like this outside of the update loop, that I know of:

1 - Custom Events.

Writing your own custom event would allow you to call something like "OnMouseMove()" outside of the update function and it would only execute when the mouse cursor's position changes.

2 - Coroutines

Creating a separate coroutine would allow you to perform this check less frequently. To do this, you make an IEnumerator and put your mouse movement logic in there. Something like:

```
IEnumerator MouseMovement()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(MouseMoved)
        {
           //Do stuff
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}
```

That coroutine would perform the check once every second while it is running. You would start the coroutine by saying:

```
StartCoroutine(MouseMovement());
```

And to stop it, you call

```
StopCoroutine(MouseMovement());
```

If you Start it when the timer reaches 0 and stop it when the cursor is moved, you can also prevent the coroutine from running all the time, only using it while the cursor is inactive.

Comment: WaitForSeconds creates a new coroutine that increments a timer and checks if done. That new coroutine is a new object each round. So in the end, that saves the input checks but still computes some and does more damage on the memory side.

Comment: Which leads us back to "Write your own custom event", which is most likely the best way to do this anyway. I don't really understand why Unity doesn't have any built-in support for detecting mouse movement though.

Answer (score 4):

This should be the good way to achieve the task, using coroutine, without any memory issue:

```
private Coroutine co_HideCursor;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") == 0 && (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") == 0))
    {
        if (co_HideCursor == null)
        {
            co_HideCursor = StartCoroutine(HideCursor());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (co_HideCursor != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(co_HideCursor);
            co_HideCursor = null;
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerator HideCursor()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    Cursor.visible = false;
}
```